# The Wall of Walls

Tags: knowledge, connect-wall

I present to you... **The Wall of Walls**!

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sniper | bauxite | marshmallow | viper |
| sparrow | absolution | modernism | pigeon |
| joplin | golden | earth | smaug |
| sergeant | gala | inspector | square |
| circle | donut | berlin | springfield |
| pentagon | granite | sandstone | falkor |
| oreo | negro | predator | smith |
| graduate | captain | independence | scholar |
| money | office | triangle | constable |
| lollipop | fuji | shockwave | albatross |
| acrobat | hunger | madeira | wailing |
| python | boa | anaconda | flash |
| silent | calendar | marble | resurrection |
| pelican | norbert | malone | covenant |
| drive | great | columbia | prometheus |
| tocantins | putumayo | illustrator | viserion |

You must sort these 64 words into 16 groups of 4 words. However, once you're finished with that, your mission is to build another wall with 16 new words, those words being the **key word** in each of those category names, and then solve it too!

For instance, if you grouped the words *galaxy*, *kart*, *party* and *odyssey* in a "*words in the title of Mario videogames*" category, you should use *Mario* as a word for the second wall (and maybe that would be part of the group "*Nintendo characters*" or "*Names beginning with an M*" in that wall). Don't worry, I think the word to be used for each category should be quite obvious (if it's the right group).

The only thing left to say is that only one of the words on the second wall is a plural. I clarify this because since you will be working with groups, the category names will probably be plural, so you should take this into account and use the singular form of the key word in all but one case.

Good luck!

**Edit**: Since the first Wall was pretty much solved, here is the 2nd wall, to avoid discrepancies:

> `post      snake      dragon     android`
> `rock      amazon     alien      missouri`
> `adobe     police     apple      bird`
> `google    shape      wall       hitman`

---

Although I've mentioned these in the comments, I'll add these here for clarification.

**Hint 1:**

> The word that should be in plural in the second wall is very fitting.

**Hint 2:**

> Stone instead of rock does work for the category I had in mind, but not as well.

**Hint 3:**

> The first category for the second wall was already found. The tags for the remaining three are *music*, *movies* and *entertainment*.

**Hint 4:**

> My other question on this site will pretty much tell you what one of the categories is (I made this before that one was solved, and I wanted someone to solve all of this first and then make the connection, but it didn't happen!)

**Hint 5:**

> The words in another category are supposed to be preceded by "the" (unless you choose the alternative word in hint 2. That word is... *cooler*).

Comment: i think this is also called a Zebra puzzle, am i right?

Comment: This is a fun puzzle format. I'll be stealing this :P

Comment: @jafe That'd be an honor, I'm a huge fan of your puzzles :)

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Wikipedia says those are the "Einstein puzzles" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebra_Puzzle). I'm not sure if this format exists already, I just wanted to jump on the connect-wall bandwagon while giving it my own little spin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> **adobe**: illustrator flash shockwave acrobat
>  **google**: calendar drive earth scholar
>  **amazon**: negro tocantins putumayo madeira (from @frogtown_j)
>  **apple**: golden gala fuji smith
>
>  These are all **tech companies**.
>
>  **police**: constable inspector sergeant captain
>  **alien**: covenant prometheus predator resurrection
>  **android**: marshmallow donut oreo lollipop (from @hexomino)
>  **walls**: berlin wailing great hunger (from @hexomino)
>
>  These are parts of **song titles on Radiohead's [OK Computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OK_Computer)** (thanks, hint 4): "Karma Police", "Subterranean Homesick Alien", "Paranoid Android", "Climbing Up the Walls".
>
>  **shape**: square circle triangle pentagon
>  **bird**: pelican albatross pigeon sparrow
>  **post**: malone office modernism graduate (from @FionaSapphire)
>  **missouri**: springfield joplin independence columbia (from @frogtown_j)
>
>  These are all parts of the titles of **2018 Best Picture Oscar [candidates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/90th_Academy_Awards)**: "The Shape of Water", "Lady Bird", "The Post", "Three Billboards Outside Ebbing, Missouri".
>
>  **snake**: viper boa anaconda python
>  **rock**: granite sandstone marble bauxite
>  **dragon**: viserion smaug falkor norbert
>  **hitman**: silent money absolution sniper (from @frogtown_j)
>
>  These are all **WrestleMania wrestlers**: Jake "The Snake" Roberts, Dwayne "The Rock" Johnson, Ricky "The Dragon" Steamboat, Bret "Hitman" Hart.

Comment: I would replace sweet with what I have (it seems more specific) although I do agree with river.

Comment: I also think my category 11 and possibly category 7 are in there somehow which would bring it up to 14.

Comment: 8/12 correct here! One of them is very close but there's a more specific word for the category, and there's another where I'm looking for a very similar word (that hexomino guessed correctly).

Comment: Almost got it now; like @Victor Perszel your groups are correct, but one name is off (although now that I think of it... it kind of works too with the category that I thought of for the second wall, but not as well), and another one should be a plural.

Since the first wall is pretty much solved, I'll say: the first group for the second wall is exactly right :)

Comment: The second one, unfortunately, isn't.

Comment: Still incorrect. The remaining three categories are a little bit more trivia-y than the first. I will add some hints if no one gets it.

Comment: Only two categories to go!

Comment: One of the examples in the last category is wrong (well, not the one I thought of, see hint 5), but that's pretty much it! That makes two walls of walls solved today ;)

Answer (score 12):

**Partial answer**

Category 1

> **Shape** - square, circle, pentagon, triangle

Category 2

> **Alien** - resurrection, predator, prometheus, covenant

Category 3

> **Dragon** - smaug, falkor, viserion, norbert

Category 4

> **Android** - oreo, lollipop, marshmallow, donut

Category 5

> **Snake** - python, boa, anaconda, viper

Category 6

> **Rock** - sandstone, granite, bauxite, marble

Category 7

> **Mountains** - negro, fuji, springfield, independence

Category 8

> **Bird** - sparrow, pigeon, albatross, pelican

Category 9

> **Adobe** - acrobat, flash, illustrator, shockwave

Category 10

> **Labels** - putumayo, columbia, silent, absolution (credit to Fiona Sapphire)

Category 11

> **Wall** - wailing, berlin, great, hunger

Category 12

> **Police** - inspector, sergeant, captain, constable (credit to jafe)

Category 13

> **Google** - earth, calendar, drive, scholar

Category 14

> **Post** - malone, office, graduate, modernism (credit to Fiona Sapphire)

Category 15

> **River** - smith, tocantins, madeira, golden (credit to jafe)

Category 16

> 

Comment: 10/13 words correct! (although one of them has an incorrect word in it)

Comment: Thanks, I think I can tell which 10 they are, jafe may have done better.

Comment: You're 11/15. 2 are far from the solution, 1 is almost right but has the wrong words which when correct will help narrow it down (I made a slight mistake in that particular category, but I think it still works), and jafe got the remaining one right, though it's close to what you have (although one word is wrong too)

Comment: This has most of what I have, so no new answer, one category you don't seem to have considered is (ROT13) NCCYR: tbyqra, tnyn, shwv, fzvgu

Answer (score 8):

Ok - I think these combined with some tweaking of the others should complete the first wall ( I'll let someone else compile the complete answer):

> Hitman (video game franchise): sniper, absolution, silent, money
> Missouri: Springfield, Joplin, Independence, Columbia
> Apple: golden, fuji, gala, smith

As far as the second wall (partial):

> Tech: Apple, Android, Google, Adobe
> The rivers from @jafe post could also be re-categorized as Amazon, which would also fit in a tech category, but could be combined with Missouri (and maybe Snake) as a rivers category...maybe adobe gets bumped from tech into another category with posts, rocks, and walls for building materials?

Comment: All three are correct, as well as your "recategorization", great job! If you can agree on all the correct categories, the second wall will be ready to be solved!

Comment: +1 Nicely done, I would have struggled to get these.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, so I'm pretty sure I made to the first wall:

> STONES: bauxite granite marble sandstone 
>  ANDROID: donut oreo marshmallow lollipop 
>  BIRDS: pelican sparrow pigeon albatross 
>  SNAKES: viper anaconda python boa 
>  GEOMETRY SHAPES: square triangle pentagon circle 
>  DRAGONS: viserion falkor smaug norbert 
>  ALIEN: resurrection predator prometheus covenant 
>  ADOBE: acrobat shockwave illustrator flash 
>  GOOGLE: earth drive scholar calendar 
>  POST: malone modernism office graduate 
>  HITMAN: sniper absolution silent money 
>  APPLE: golden gala fuji smith 
> AMAZON RIVER: putumayo madeira tocantins negro 
> WALL: great hunger wailing berlin 
> POLICE: sergeant captain constable inspector 
> MISSOURI: columbia joplin springfield independence

I will update when I have the second wall, but for me one is already obvious

> TECHNOLOGY COMPANIES: android adobe google apple

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Why don't you take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) and earn a badge? Very nice first post!

Comment: All the words are grouped correctly, great job! One of the category names used is not correct, and you have to choose just one word for the second wall (and remember, only one of them is a plural... Accidentally, the one that is is quite fitting...)

Answer (score 4):

Partial:

> ROCK: bauxite, marble, granite, sandstone
> ANDROID: marshmallow, oreo, lollipop, donut
> SNAKE: viper, python, boa, anaconda
> BIRD: sparrow, pigeon, albatross, ppelican
> SHAPE: square, circle, triangle, pentagon
> ALIEN: prometheus, resurrection, predator, covenant 
> ADOBE: illustrator, shockwave, acrobat, flash  
> POST: malone, office, graduate, modernism
> POLICE: constable, sergeant, captain, inspector
> DRAGON: falker, norbert, smaug, viserion
> GOOGLE: earth, calendar, drive, scholar
> RECORD LABEL: putumayo, columbia, silent, absolution

Partial for the second wall:

> TECH COMPANIES: Google, Adobe, Android
> CREATURES: Alien, Bird, Dragon, Snake

Comment: Nice answer +1. Have you seen my category 11? I think this might be one of the remaining categories?

Comment: 11/12 correct here! I'll refrain to comment on the second wall until someone completes the first one.

Answer (score 2):

For the final wall:

> Third letter 'a' : dragon, snake, amazon, shape
>  Double letter : google, missouri, wall, apple
>  Exactly three distinct vowels : adobe, alien, android, police
>  Change second letter to an 'a' : post, rock, bird, hitman

The last one is a bit stretched maybe...

Comment: That is a great answer, but not what I had in mind. Like the answers on the first wall, the groupings are kind of trivia-y, not related to word properties.

Answer (score 0):

What about this category for the second wall

> **Bands**: (The) Police, (The) Androids, (The) Birds, (The) Walls