# Wall of walls featuring Elvis

Tags: knowledge, connect-wall

```
arch        atlas     bb        bengal
berlin      brown     bull      charles
crouching   death     deficit   dollar
donald      elvis     extra     fallen
film        fish      fishing   gamma
gates       guardian  hook      inter
lame        larry     lima      loan
louis       mallard   manta     merlin
mo          monaco    morgan    morning
mosquito    murray    north     oz
panda       patrick   paul      peking
peter       phoebe    polar     pool
prometheus  radagast  rhea      rights
rock        rodney    ron       siberian
silver      sofia     sparrow   sting
teddy       tony      whale     woods
```

Step 1: Sort the words into 16 groups of four. All of these groups have a one-word title, which is always plural.

Step two: Sort the titles into four groups of four. What is the common theme?

Comment: Idea shamelessly taken from @NudgeNudge's [The Wall of Walls](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/77624). If you like this one, please help solve the original as well. I'm stuck!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Complete, but quite likely wrong:

> Looking like NHL/NBA/MLB/NFL teams:
>  **angels**: [arch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archangel) - [death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel_of_Death) - [fallen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallen_angel) - [guardian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardian_angel)
> **bears**: [brown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_bear) - [panda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_panda) - [polar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_bear) - [teddy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teddy_bear)
> **bills**: [dollar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_one-dollar_bill) - [gates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Gates) - [murray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Murray) - [rights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_of_rights)
> **capitals**: [berlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin) - [lima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lima) - [monaco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monaco) - [sofia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sofia)
> **ducks**: [donald](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Duck) - [lame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lame_duck_(politics)) - [mallard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mallard) - [peking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peking_duck)
> **hawks**: [deficit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deficit_hawk) - [fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawkfish) - [mo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohawk_people) - [tony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hawk)
> **kings**: [bb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B.B._King) - [elvis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_Presley) - [larry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_King) - [rodney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodney_King)
> **nets**: [extra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extranet) - [fishing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fishing_net) - [inter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet) - [mosquito](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosquito_net)
> **pirates**: [morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Morgan) - [hook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Hook) - [silver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_John_Silver) - [sparrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Sparrow)
> **rays**: [charles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_Charles) - [gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_ray) - [manta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manta_ray) - [sting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stingray)
> **saints**: [louis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Louis) - [paul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_the_Apostle) - [patrick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Patrick) - [peter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Peter)
> **sharks**: [bull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bull_shark) - [loan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loan_shark) - [pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pool_shark) - [whale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whale_shark)
> **stars**: [film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Movie_star) - [morning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morning_Star) - [north](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polaris) - [rock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_Star)
> **tigers**: [bengal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bengal_tiger) - [crouching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crouching_Tiger,_Hidden_Dragon) - [siberian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siberian_tiger) - [woods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger_Woods)
> **titans**: [atlas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_(mythology)) - [phoebe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoebe_(Titaness)) - [prometheus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prometheus) - [rhea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhea_(mythology))
> **wizards**: [merlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merlin) - [oz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizard_of_Oz_(character)) - [radagast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radagast) - [ron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ron_Weasley)
> **MLB**: [Angels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Angeles_Angels) - [Pirates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pittsburgh_Pirates) - [Rays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tampa_Bay_Rays) - [Tigers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detroit_tigers)
> **NBA**: [Kings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacramento_Kings) - [Hawks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlanta_Hawks) - [Nets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooklyn_Nets) - [Wizards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington_Wizards)
> **NFL**: [Bears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Bears) - [Bills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_Bills) - [Saints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Orleans_Saints) - [Titans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennessee_Titans)
> **NHL**: [Capitals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington_Capitals) - [Ducks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaheim_Ducks) - [Sharks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Jose_Sharks) - [Stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dallas_Stars)

Comment: Looks correct to me. Nice job!